# Subscript to \rangle, horizontal spacing

Tags: math-mode

I need a command that wraps argument #1 in `\left\langle`-`\right\rangle` and places #2 as a subscript to the closing `\rangle`,
like the command `\simple` in my MWE.

However, the horizontal spacing between the angle and the subscript gets awkwardly big for larger angles.

My first attempt in command `\better` uses a fixed negative spacing, but that's an improvement only for one particular vertical size.
What I need is a variant that chooses an appropriate offset depending on the vertical size of #1.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\simple}[2]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle_{#2}}
\newcommand{\better}[2]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle_{\hspace*{-0.8ex}#2}}

\begin{document}
simple:
$\displaystyle \simple{\frac{a}{b}}{x}$
desired: 
$\displaystyle \better{\frac{a}{b}}{x}$
however:
$\displaystyle \better{a}{x}$
$\displaystyle \better{\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{b}}{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

Answer (score 3):

Don't indiscriminately add `\left` and `\right`.

Here's my suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\anglebrackets}{\langle}{\rangle}
\NewDocumentCommand{\better}{some{_^}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% *
    \anglebrackets*{#3}%
    \IfValueT{#4}{_{\!#4}}% subscript
    \IfValueT{#5}{^{\!#5}}% superscript
  }{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
      \anglebrackets{#3}%
      \IfValueT{#4}{_{#4}}% subscript
      \IfValueT{#5}{^{#5}}% superscript
    }{%
      \anglebrackets[#2]{#3}%
      \IfValueT{#4}{_{\!#4}}% subscript
      \IfValueT{#5}{^{\!#5}}% superscript
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\better{a+b} \\
\better{a+b}_{x} \\
\better[\Big]{a+b}_{x} \\
\better*{\frac{a}{b}}_{x}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

If there is a subscript, a slight nudging is applied. The same for superscripts.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that employs `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP`, a macro provided by the [mathtools](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, to create a better version of the `\better` macro [pun intended]. You can call `\better` *as is*, with an explicit sizing directive, e.g., `\better[\big]`, or as `\better*` in order to make LaTeX figure out the size of the angle-bracket delimiters automatically. If the angle-bracket delimiters are very large, an extra alignment nudge may be needed for the subscript term.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\better}[2]%
    {}{\langle}{\rangle}{_{\!#2}}{#1}

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle
\better{a}{x} \quad
\better[\Big]{\frac{a}{b}}{x} \quad
\better*{\frac{a}{b}}{x} \quad
\better*{\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{b}}{\!x}$

\end{document}
```